# Ejecutar script php y enviarle argumentos desde node.js

Tags: php, nodejs

Tengo un script en PHP que recibe 3 argumentos para insertar en una base de datos

```
php app.php "Arg1" "Arg2" "Arg3"
```

Cuando lo ejecuto desde consola lo puedo hacer sin ningun problema, para llamarlo desde mi script de node.js intento con:

```
var exec = require("child_process").exec;
    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        exec("php app.php", function(error, stdout, stderr) {
            console.log("ESPERO QUE NO TENGA ERROR: ", error);
            if (!error) {
                res.send(stdout);
            }
        });
```

Ese código no hace nada, incluso no encuentro la forma de mandarle argumentos. ¿Saben cual es la forma correcta de ejecutar un script php y enviarle los argumentos desde node.js?

Comment: La sintaxis para enviarle argumentos es exactamente la misma que usas desde la consola, es decir, `exec('php app.php "Arg1" "Arg2" "Arg3"', function(...`. ¿No has intentado hacerlo así?

Comment: Ya lo intente así amigo y no funciono.

Answer (score 1):

En todos los casos, he visto la respuesta, que no se puede hacer. Lo cual no es del todo correcto. Dado que puede ejecutar PHP en la línea de comando, y Node.js puede ejecutar fácilmente programas a través de la línea de comando.

**¿Cuales son los beneficios?**

- Fácil colaboración entre equipos con diferentes conocimientos.
- PHP es realmente bueno y fácil para crear y lanzar scripts rápidos
- No es necesario ejecutar varios servidores si se necesitan tanto
  Node.js y PHP

**¿Cuáles son los inconvenientes?**

- Más posibilidades para debilidades de seguridad
- Rendimiento no muy bueno
- Es fácil dispararse en el pie

Tendrias que reinventar la rueda, osea programar tu mismo los metodos `$ _GET`, `$ _REQUEST`, etc. Esto porque tendrías que programar tu servidor, entonces... no creo que quieras hacer esto, hay un pequeño equipo que trabaja en ello  https://github.com/fnobi/php-express

Si ya conoces PHP y estás aprendiendo Node, probablemente tengas la tendencia de programar las cosas "duras" en PHP, por lo que no aprenderás la manera de hacerlo en node.

> Por supuesto, es probable que haya más inconvenientes y beneficios.

Te dejo un articulo que detalla mas esta parte ya que seria muy engorroso colocar todo este contenido aca: [Articulo](https://medium.com/@MartinMouritzen/how-to-run-php-in-node-js-and-why-you-probably-shouldnt-do-that-fb12abe955b0)